# ESD pins of CM1624

Tags: esd, sd, emmc

I am considering to design SD interface with a CPU. For ESD and EMI, there are some ICs that can prevent these issues with RLC filter and TVS diodes such as CM1624. What I am wondering about is that what are for ESD1 and ESD3 pins of CM1624?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you link to the datasheet of your CM1624? also, "these issues with RLC filters and TVS diodes": What specifically are you referring to? Please elaborate.

Comment: Here is the datasheet link https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/cm1624-d.pdf  . When I say RLC filters and TVS diodes, what I mean is that IC consists of TVS diodes for ESD and filters to cope with EMI issue. I believe that capacitance of RLC filter is TVS diode parasitic capacitance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are just extra pins you can use for any arbitrary purpose, like for the card insertion or write protection contacts of the SD card holder.

Comment: Yes https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/cm1624-d.pdf

Comment: @Justme thanks for your answer.